# Remove second div with same class

Tags: jquery, class

In my HTML are two divs with identical classes. If I want to remove the div by class, both of them get removed. How can I (whilst using Jquery) remove the second div by class? Is there a way for it to 'skip' the first div it finds?

The code looks like this:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="randomdiv">
    <div class="oneofthetwodivs">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="randomdiv"></div>
  <div class="randomdiv"></div>
  <div class="oneofthetwodivs">
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to target the second element with that class (it is zero based):

```
$('.oneofthetwodivs').eq(1).remove();
```

Comment: Well, that's some quick service! Thanks allot!

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
$(".oneofthetwodivs").eq(1).remove();
```

or

```
$(".oneofthetwodivs:last").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `:nth-of-type(2)` on your class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.removeMe:nth-of-type(2)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="removeMe">This is the first div</div>
<div class="removeMe">This is the SECOND div, should not show</div>
<div class="removeMe">This is the third div</div>
```